# Как превратить ключи с пустыми значениями в значения, которые ни на что не указывают и нормально переводятся в JSON?

Tags: php, массивы, json, json.net, json-encode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возникла проблема с массивом. По ключам "софт" и "аксессуары" другие ключи, но у каждого из них есть значение null. У меня задача перевести этот массив в json, но json_encode() приводит к тому, что, например, "безопасность" превращается в "софт":{"безопасность":null,"системные":null, Как сделать так, чтобы было: "софт":{"безопасность","системные"}, то есть, насколько я понимаю, нужно, чтобы "безопасность" и другие элементы не были ключами и не содержали в себе никакого значения совсем.. Как этого добиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$array = array_map(fn($i) => array_keys($i), $array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам нужно, чтобы элементы массива первого уровня содержали в себе обычные массивы.

```php
$myArray = array(
    "игры" => [],
    "софт" => ["безопасность", "системные", "редакторы"],
    "аксессуары" => ["steam", "skylanders", "tobii", "xbox"]
);
```

Достаточно просто не указывать никакого значения, тогда у вас будут элементы массива вместо ключей.

PS

Можно использовать как квадратные скобки, так и конструкцию `array()`, суть не меняется

Comment: Да, к этому и пришел в итоге, намудрил или правильнее сказать "натупил" ) Спасибо за помощь!